# Check if a process is closed/not running, then restart the application

Tags: batch-file

Below is the script I am using to detect if my application is being closed. If it is closed the application will restart again. The application should run in the background as I am running this on startup.

run.bat

```
@echo off
:Restart
start "AppNAME" /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\App\App.exe"
goto Restart
```

How can I **hide** the command windows after running the .bat file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement here is a vbs file that will run the batch file in background.just past the vbs file in startup and the batch file somewhere else.

```
REM 0 = hide window, 1 = show window (useful for debugging)
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run """" & "file.bat" & """" & sargs, 0, False
Set WshShell = Nothing
```